# Iptables -j REJECT unavailable

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I am somewhat new to  Linux networking and running in to a issue with iptables I am just not making any headway on.

Two notes before I get in too it. iptables is version 1.4.14, and it is a custom embedded server using custom distro of Linux.

The issues I am having is that -j REJECT parameter is unavailable. If I enter something like (as root) "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT" the error "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." is returned.

If I enter the same thing with -j DROP instead iptables accepts it and works without issue.

So the question is what is missing in my installation that is causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the external module with `modprobe ipt_REJECT` and try again. DROP is in native, but REJECT is optionnal

If it is a custom kernel, you maybe need to add it in the kernel compilation. Check the /boot/config file if it exists.

Comment: I will give that a shot!